# How to remove navbar completely in my app?

Tags: android

I am creating an android app so that the nav bar and title bar needs to be hidden. I am able to do that from activity as explained in developer.android.com.

But I need to achieve this in whole my application by defining it only once.

From some forum that the below code will do that:

```
 <style name="FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

I applied this style to my manifest and bang, the title bar is gone.. But sadly the nav bar remains.. How could we remove navbar too like this??

Please help

Comment: share activity xml code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps always forcing [immersive-mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) will achieve what you need? You can extend Activity or AppCompatActivity and add the following code (taken from that page):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

This way every time the window has focus it will have sitcky immersivity which will make it cover the nav and status bars. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "title bar" though.

So, make a new class. Call is ImmersiveActivity e.g.

```
public class ImmersiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
}
```

Now, when you want to make a new activity simply do:

```
public class SomeOtherActivity extends ImmersiveActivity {

}
```

And in this way every new activity based on this class should automatically launch in immersive mode (when it has focus).

Comment: But this will affect only that activity right! I need this in application level result

Comment: Add this as a method on a new activity e.g. FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity then every new activity you make simply is of type FullScreenActivity

Comment: How to make new activity a type of other activity?

Comment: See now if that's helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166086/discussion-between-dirk-conrad-coetsee-and-karthik-cp).

Comment: Yes.. That worked and solved my issue.. Still, i have to extend this all activity! I hope there no way to add this only in application level?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this with themes or in xml but stand to be corrected

Answer (score 1):

In activity `onCreate()` add below lines above `setContentView()` like

```
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: This will only applicable to that activity right? I need this application level

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml

add this to the application tag:

```
 <application
    ....
    android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
```

And in styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This will only remove title bar.Nav bar still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try include to **Activity** in **manifest.xml**

```
<activity
        ...
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
...
```

Comment: Still applicable to that activity only